# Is there any programs out there you can paste WSDL document and get sample XML packets

Tags: xml, web-services, soap

I'm trying to understand a WSDL file in order to build a SOAP Body to go in a SOAP envelope. The language I use doesn't automatically build it for me. What's the best way to learn how to construct XML packets manually?

Many thanks,

b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/Working-with-soapUI/main-window.html). When importing WSDL (both from URL or local file) you can create sample requests for every operation. Moreover, you can create a mock server that, when running, will return sample responses as well. Very sophisticated tool.